# How do I make the XNamespace on F#?

Tags: xml, f#

C# Sample:

```
XNamespace aw = "http://www.adventure-works.com";
```

How does F # I write?

I try that:

```
let ns : XNamespace = "URI ADDRESS";;
```

F# Say Error

Answer (score 12, accepted):

F# doesn't have implicit operators, so:

```
let ns = XNamespace.op_Implicit "http://www.adventure-works.com"
```

If you use this a lot, you might want to put it in a function or operator to hide the ugliness a bit, e.g:

```
let inline xns n = XNamespace.op_Implicit n
let ns = xns "http://www.adventure-works.com"
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response.
Implicit is I saw in MSDN, I don't understood the writing's on op_Implicit.

Comment: What looks like a implicit cast operator from C#, is actually a static method called `op_Implicit`, in the IL. And F# doesn't have support for implicit operators, so it allows you to access that method directly.

Answer (score 11):

F# doesn't have implicit operators, but you can use the [`Get()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace.get.aspx):

```
let ns = XNamespace.Get "URI ADDRESS"
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. Set in the can did not want to Get. :-)